# How can you programmatically get the endpoint value of the root domain for an S3 Bucket (static website) that was assigned by AWS via the SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

For example: example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com?

[image: Here is the value in the GUI]

How can I get this value programmatically via the SDK?  I can't seem to find it:

link to docs:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3.html

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466716/how-do-i-get-the-aws-s3-website-endpoint-url-through-the-api

Answer (score 2):

The value doesn't appear to be exposed by the S3 API, itself.

It is, however, easily derived from the bucket location, which is accessible [via the S3 REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html), though it isn't obvious from skimming the docs whether this is implemented in the Ruby SDK, either, in spite of its presence in the underlying API. I didn't find it.

But the web site endpoints are always in this form:

```
${bucket}.s3-website-${region}.amazonaws.com
```

In us-east-1, as shown in the screen shot, the endpoint for a bucket named `example.com` fits this pattern, `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region